# Why does hitting Control + C when in an application launched from a script, break the script?

Tags: bash, scripts

To jump straight in:

```
while true; do
    #---  MENU LOGIC HERE, stick response in $MENUEXIT

    #----Deal with responses here

    if [ $S1 == $MENUEXIT ];
    then
            tail -f /path-to-file
    else
            sleep 2
    fi
done
```

I've tried to keep this as simple as possible, if you need more, let me know.

Basically, I am sticking a menu in  a loop, so, if there is incorrect user input or a command finishes, it is meant to re-display the menu.

It worked fine, until I added the tail command.

If I choose the tail option from the menu, the tail command gets launched fine - but, if I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, I would like tail to terminate and the menu to be displayed, but it instead both terminates tail **AND** the script.

I have tried various things such as continues/traps and more, but, I have hit a brick wall and would like some help please?!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you send a signal like `SIGINT` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>) or `SIGSTOP` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>) *from a terminal*, the signal is sent to the foreground process group. That is, the group comprising of the foreground job (your script), and any child processes it has in the foreground (the `tail` command). This causes all these processes to exit (or do whatever it is they do by handling the signal). You can test the difference by sending a signal using the `kill` command:

In one terminal, execute this script (I'm calling it `test` in the following commands):

```
#! /bin/bash

while true
do
    if [[ $1 = a ]]
    then
        yes 
    else
        echo no
        sleep 2
    fi
done
```

In another, execute these commands:

```
pstree -ps $(pgrep -f test)
pkill -f test
pstree -ps $(pgrep -f yes)
```

The output of the commands would be something like this:

```
init(1)───lightdm(1032)───lightdm(1154)───init(1173)───x-terminal-emul(17009)───bash(24262)───test.sh(24996)───yes(24997)
# No output for pkill
init(1)───lightdm(1032)───lightdm(1154)───init(1173)───yes(24997)
```

<sup><sub>(The actual numbers and programs may vary, but the first init will always have [pid 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13290/init-process-ancestor-of-all-processes).)</sub></sup>
As you can see, the `yes` command wasn't killed, and got attached to `init` because its parent was killed. It's still merrily printing `y`s on the first terminal. So kill it with `pkill -f yes`. Now repeat the experiment, with one change. Instead of `pkill -f test`, do:

```
kill -INT -25165 
# Use the pid of test.sh given in parentheses in the output of pstree 
# instead of 25165
```

Note the leading `-`. In Linux, for the `kill` command, `-25165` is the process group, whose leader has pid `25165`. Thus, this command is the equivalent of sending an interrupt from the terminal.

Of course, the exact behaviour depends on the configuration of the TTY, the login shell and so on. This is as far as my understanding goes. Further reading:

- [Sending and Trapping Signals](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/SignalTrap)
- [Preventing propagation of SIGINT to Parent Process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80975/preventing-propagation-of-sigint-to-parent-process)
- [The TTY demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php)

---

I suggest:

1. Sending the `tail` to the background
2. Trap the signal
3. Kill the background process.
4. Remove the trap

An example:

```
#! /bin/bash

kill_jobs ()
{
    kill %1
}

while true
do
    if [[ $1 = "a" ]]
    then
        trap kill_jobs INT
        tail -f /var/log/syslog &
        wait %%
        shift #You don't need to shift, I just didn't want loop tail on this example
        trap - INT
    else
        echo some output
        sleep 2
    fi
done
```

This can become very powerful, by using different functions for trapping, and each doing their own clean up work.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for this and I'll try it shortly. Os it basically killing the entire process tree when I do control + c or is something else going on? It is great you provided an answer, but, I'm trying to get a deeper understanding of Linux so I can understand why these things happen the way they do!

Comment: that is great! Thanks for both the explanation and the fix! Works great and now I fully understand why it is happening! :)

Comment: @Sneetsher added.